# How to build a Linq Expression for selecting nested objects?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using a generic repository to retrieve objects from the database and while lazy loading is not available in EntityFramework Core, sometimes I would need to select related objects.

The repo code looks like this:

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and telling it to select a related object is simple:

```
.GetSingle(id,x=>x.ObjectviaFK)`
```

I can't wrap my head around building an expression that will allow selecting nested objects (similar to `.Include(...).ThenInclude(...)` from context), something like `.GetSingle(id, x=>Parent,parent=>Grand,grand=>GrandGrand)`. How do I do this?

Comment: Usually I use a non-linq recursive helper method that is called by a linq query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem if you don't want to change your `GetSingle` you could just put in the correct lambdas to include the nested objects?

```
`.GetSingle(id, x=>x.Parent, x=>x.Parent.Grand, x=>x.Parent.GrandGrand)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do justice to the question how to handle `.Include(...).ThenInclude(...)` which is far more difficult to do dynamically than just adding `Include`s to a query.